# calculating means with input from a user in python

Tags: python, function, calculator, mean

i am trying to create a function  that calculates arithmetic mean,geometric mean and harmonic mean of numbers the user gives me. the result  should be like: for number 4 and 9
The arithmetic mean of the numbers is 6.5
The geometric mean of the numbers is 6
The harmonic mean of the numbers is 5.538461538461538

this is my code :

```
  import math
  def fancy_mean():
      number=input("Please enter the numbers, one in each line: ")
      total_arithmetic=0
      multiplication_result_geometric=1
      harmonical_total=0
      count_of_numbers=0
      list_of_numbers=[]
      while  number!="":
          number=float(number)
          list_of_numbers.append(number)
          count_of_numbers+=1
          for i in list_of_numbers:
              total_arithmetic=total_arithmetic+i
              arithmatic_mean=float(total_arithmetic/count_of_numbers)
              multiplication_result_geometric=multiplication_result_geometric*i
              geomatric_mean=float(math.sqrt(multiplication_result_geometric))
              harmonical_total=harmonical_total+(1/i)
             harmonical_mean=float(count_of_numbers/harmonical_total)

      number=input("Please enter the numbers, one in each line: ")
    if not list_of_numbers:
      return
print("The arithmetic mean of the numbers is",arithmatic_mean)
print("The geometric mean of the numbers is",geomatric_mean)
print("The harmonic mean of the numbers is",harmonical_mean)
```

but  i keep in  getting wrong results and i dont know why ?
he arithmetic mean of the numbers is 8.5
The geometric mean of the numbers is 12.0
The harmonic mean of the numbers is 3.2727272727272725
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMGTx.png)

Comment: IndentationError's (as in multiple). And not the code you run - currently it has an endless loop because you never reset `number` inside your `while number != "":` loop. Indentation matters, please [edit] and fix your code. Beside that - you never call `fancy_mean()` - so nothing should happen at all. [mre] !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constantly recalculating the means instead of ingesting all the numbers and then calculating it once. I moved the calculation outside the while-loop:

```py
import math

def fancy_mean():
    number=input("Please enter the numbers, one in each line: ")
    total_arithmetic=0
    multiplication_result_geometric=1
    harmonical_total=0
    count_of_numbers=0
    list_of_numbers=[]
    
    while number != "":
        number=float(number)
        list_of_numbers.append(number)
        count_of_numbers+=1
        number=input("Please enter the numbers, one in each line: ")

    for i in list_of_numbers:
        total_arithmetic=total_arithmetic+i
        arithmatic_mean=float(total_arithmetic/count_of_numbers)
        multiplication_result_geometric=multiplication_result_geometric*i
        geomatric_mean=float(math.sqrt(multiplication_result_geometric))
        harmonical_total=harmonical_total+(1/i)
        harmonical_mean=float(count_of_numbers/harmonical_total)

    if not list_of_numbers:
        return

    print("The arithmetic mean of the numbers is",arithmatic_mean)
    print("The geometric mean of the numbers is",geomatric_mean)
    print("The harmonic mean of the numbers is",harmonical_mean)

fancy_mean()
```

Comment: thank you it worked , and also i should get None if the list is empty meaning    a user didnt enter any numbers  but in this case i get Process finished with exit code 0/ how can i fix it ?

Comment: @ZivAqua Just change the part that says`if not list_of_numbers: return`

Comment: A `return` statement without a value will return a None, so I don't really understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a strong reason not to use existing implementations of these functions, I would suggest that you declare `fancy_mean` and use the SciPy and NumPy implementations of [geometric mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.gmean.html), [harmonic mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hmean.html), and [mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Furthermore, the code is lacking a `return` statement, and it will probably because a possible infinite loop (I'm assuming the indentation is OK in your environment).

Here is a SciPy/NumPy version of your function, without the prompt for new numbers:

```py
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean, hmean
import numpy as np

my_numbers = [4, 9]

def fancy_mean(numbers):
    return gmean(numbers), hmean(numbers), np.mean(numbers)

fancy_mean(my_numbers)

# >>> (6.0, 5.538461538461538, 6.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the intermediate means by moving the print statement inside the loop, fixing plenty of mis-spellings of your variables and ask for new numbers inside the loop as well. You leave the loop with a `break` statement if an empty string is provided and you handle non-float inputs graciously:

```
import math

def fancy_mean():
    arithmetic_total = 0
    multiplication_result_geometric = 1
    harmonical_total = 0
    numbers = []
    len_numbers = 0
    while True:
        number = input(f"\nPlease enter the next number, currently you have {numbers}:")
        if not number:      # empty string: exit
            break
        try:
            n = float(number)
            numbers.append(n)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number!")
            continue  # back to the start of the loop


        len_numbers += 1       # you can use len(numbers) instead as well
        
        # sum numbers / count numbers
        arithmetic_total += n
        arithmetic_mean = float(arithmetic_total/len_numbers)

        # nth root of product of n numbers 
        multiplication_result_geometric *= n
        geometric_mean= multiplication_result_geometric ** (1/len_numbers) 

        # count numbers / sum (1/number for number in numbers)
        harmonical_total += 1/n
        harmonical_mean = len_numbers / harmonical_total

        print("The arithmetic mean of the numbers is", arithmetic_mean)
        print("The geometric mean of the numbers is", geometric_mean)
        print("The harmonic mean of the numbers is", harmonical_mean)

fancy_mean()
```

Output:

```
Please enter the next number, currently you have []: 1
The arithmetic mean of the numbers is 1.0
The geometric mean of the numbers is 1.0
The harmonic mean of the numbers is 1.0

Please enter the next number, currently you have [1.0]: 4
The arithmetic mean of the numbers is 2.5
The geometric mean of the numbers is 2.0
The harmonic mean of the numbers is 1.6

Please enter the next number, currently you have [1.0, 4.0]: 4
The arithmetic mean of the numbers is 3.0
The geometric mean of the numbers is 2.5198420997897464
The harmonic mean of the numbers is 2.0
```